# LLVM-IR: How call intrinsic function in javacpp

Tags: intrinsics, llvm-ir, javacpp

How call intrinsic function in javacpp? 
For example, I want to call llvm.sadd.with.overflow intrinsic function.

Comment: I solve this problem.
In module you should add function with specific signature and function name with you want call.